# find same node from two single linked list. Can't use hash, Can not be O(n^2) complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

find same node from two single linked lists. Can't use hash, Can not be O(n^2) complexity.

Please give some hints.
thank you so much.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, what have you tried?  Do you have any ideas as to what might work?

Comment: What is the content of the linked list? Is it storing numbers? Strings? Complex data types? or is it arbitrary for the purposes of the question?

Comment: if you are trying to find out intersection of two linked list then it is explained at http://code-forum.blogspot.com/2011/01/intersection-of-two-linked-list.html

Comment: Without clarification from OP adding the [homework] tag is NOT OK. I have removed it. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort the two linked lists and then do a linear pass to find two nodes that are equal. This is 2*O(NlogN) + 2*O(N) = O(NlogN).

Comment: This would only work if the resultant item was in the same position on the list

Comment: @Zoomzoom83:  Once the lists are sorted, you can iterate over both of them at the same time.  For each iteration, test whether the two elements have the same value; if not, increment the iterator that points to the smaller of the two elements.

Comment: @James I think we have a winner. You should submit that as a full answer.